# Upon clicking a link in a table row, change the cell value of the corresponding MYSQL database record?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with fields structured like this:

```
id fname lname auxiliary calling releaseFrom user date notes status
```

I have a table that corresponds to those same fields. At the very end of each row, I have a link that when clicked, should change the 'status' field of the corresponding row to 'Approved'. I am having some trouble finding out how to specify which record to change once the link is clicked. I assume I need to target the ID of the correct row somehow but I can't figure out how to do that.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianLender/er6tvtnk/) is a very basic setup of the table that I have. When the 'Approved' link is clicked, it should then change the MYSQL database record. Does anyone know how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution

When you build your table on your server-side be sure to have something like this

```
<td><a href="your_script.php?action=approve&id=<?php echo RECORD_ID ?>">Archive</a></td>
```

Then the HTML would look like following. As you can see, you'll have this link for each record printed

```
<!-- HTML --> 
<tr>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>Jerry</td>
    <td>PFR</td>
    <td><a href="your_script.php?action=approve&id=111">Archive</a></td>
</tr>
```

While the code on server-side should look like this

```
//PHP [your_sccript.php]
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'approve'){
    mysqli_query("
      UPDATE your_table
      SET status = 'approved'  // or use an integer, 1 in this case
      WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'] . "
   ");
   // if you use the second solution echo something here to the console, like
   echo "Post " . $_GET['id'] . " has been approved";
}
```

Second solution

If you don't want to reload your page after every click on `Archive` link, use Ajax.

This is a table row generated on server-side by PHP. As you may notice, the JavaScript `approve()` function now has two arguments; the second one is the `id` of the record while the first one is the reference of the element being clicked.

```
<!-- HTML --> 
<tr>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>Jerry</td>
    <td>PFR</td>
    <td><span onclick="approve(this, 111);">Archive</span></td>
</tr>

// JavaScript
var approve = function(obj, id){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "your_script.php?action=approve&id=" + id;
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      // at this point we need to get the first parent TR to whom the SPAN belongs
      // if you want to replace only the TD (the parent of the SPAN)
      // change the TR to TD within the while loop below
      var tr = obj.parentNode;
      while(tr.nodeName != 'TR'){
        tr = tr.parentNode;
      }
      // as we have it, let's replace it with the response (new row) from the server
      tr.outerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};

// PHP
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'approve'){
  // first, update the row
  mysqli_query("UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id = " . $_GET["id"] . "");
  // and then select, and echo it back like this 
  $set = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $_GET["id"] . "");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($set, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo '<TR>' . 'ALL_THE_TD' . '</TR>';
  // so, we echo the same row, but the updated one
  // this will be used by JavaScript function to replace the old TR 
}
```

Comment: Of course, `$_GET['id']` should be properly escaped and/or validated before being used. And since you're using `mysqli_*` calls, you should use `prepare` and `bind_params` rather than `query`.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for catching that missing quote ;) With `mysqli` I just wanted to let him know that he should use it and I hope he will use other related things as well :)

Comment: @hex494D49 I tried to use the AJAX solution you gave me and it works great, except the page doesn't update. I click the link and it appears that nothing happens until I manually refresh the page and then it shows that the updates really were done. Do you know what I might have missed?

Comment: @BrianLender Check the updated second solution and let me know if you need any further assistance.